# Why does C# expect a ";" in my ItemTemplates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itemtemplate

I have a page with the following code:

```
      <ItemTemplate>
        <a id="el_<%# ((MyType)Container.DataItem).FirstName) %>" 
            class='activate_edit_modal' popupId="modal_window" title="Click to edit.">
          Edit
        </a>
      </ItemTemplate>
```

When I try to run the page, I get the following error: `CS1002: ; expected` with the line directly under `<ItemTemplate>` highlighted.  Why is this?  I thought that When you use `<%# XXXXX %>`, you don't use a semicolon.

I tried changing this to `<%# Eval("FirstName") %>` and that seems to work.

Comment: Did you try <%((MyType)Container.DataItem).FirstName);%>    ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, I just realized that I have an extra ")" which caused the error.

`<%# ((MyType)Container.DataItem).FirstName) %>` needs to be
`_<%# ((MyType)Container.DataItem).FirstName %>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried single quotes for the id attribute?

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <a id='el_<%# ((MyType)Container.DataItem).FirstName) %>' 
    class="activate_edit_modal" popupId="modal_window" title="Click to edit.">
    Edit
  </a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This.  I've had this problem myself a few times - single quotes may not completely resolve the issue, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Although I found that this is actually a syntax error on my part, I'm curious about what sort of issue single-quotes would actually solve, other than an issue involving a string literal containing double-quotes.